# How Can I Set Textboxes on Radio Button Click

Tags: reactjs

I have 4 handle change functions performing different actions I need to change the handle change function when we select an option on the radio button

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getCompany } from "../actions/company"
import "./css/InvoiceAdd.css"
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import "./css/Togglebox.css"


export class InvoiceSales extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Invoice_Date: '',
            company_name: '',
            GSTIN: '',
            invoice_no: '',
            percentage: 0,
            net: 0,
            igst: 0,
            cgst: 0,
            sgst: 0,
            total_invoice: 0,
            checked:true,
            checked1:false

        };
        console.log(this.state);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.handlenum1Change = this.handlenum1Change.bind(this);
        this.handlenum2Change = this.handlenum2Change.bind(this);
        this.handlenum3Change=this.handlenum3Change.bind(this);
        this.handlenum4Change=this.handlenum4Change.bind(this);
    }

    handlenum1Change = evt => {
        const percentage = Number(evt.target.value);
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          percentage,
          igst: ((percentage * prevState.net)/100),
        //   sgst:(((percentage * prevState.net)/100)/2),
        //   cgst:(((percentage * prevState.net)/100)/2),
          total_invoice:((percentage * prevState.net)/100)+prevState.net
        }));
      };

      handlenum2Change = evt => {
        const net = Number(evt.target.value);
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          net,
          igst: ((prevState.percentage * net)/100),
        //   sgst: (((prevState.percentage * net)/100)/2),
        //   cgst: (((prevState.percentage * net)/100)/2),
          total_invoice:((prevState.percentage * net)/100)+net
        }));
      };

      handlenum3Change = evt => {
        const percentage = Number(evt.target.value);
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          percentage,
        //   igst: ((percentage * prevState.net)/100),
          sgst:(((percentage * prevState.net)/100)/2),
          cgst:(((percentage * prevState.net)/100)/2),
          total_invoice:((percentage * prevState.net)/100)+prevState.net
        }));
      };

      handlenum4Change = evt => {
        const net = Number(evt.target.value);
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          net,
        //   igst: ((prevState.percentage * net)/100),
          sgst: (((prevState.percentage * net)/100)/2),
          cgst: (((prevState.percentage * net)/100)/2),
          total_invoice:((prevState.percentage * net)/100)+net
        }));
      };


    componentDidMount() {
        document.body.classList.add("background-black");
        this.props.getCompany()
    }



    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.body.classList.remove("background-black");
    }

    onChange = event => {   
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    };




    onCreate(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let Invoice = {
            Invoice_Date: this.state.Invoice_Date,
            company_name: this.state.company_name,
            GSTIN: this.state.GSTIN,
            invoice_no: this.state.invoice_no,
            percentage: this.state.percentage,
            net: this.state.net,
            igst: this.state.igst,
            sgst: this.state.sgst,
            total_invoice: this.state.total_invoice
        };
        console.log(Invoice);
        this.props.postData(Invoice);
        this.setState({
            Invoice_Date: '',
            company_name: '',
            GSTIN: '',
            invoice_no: '',
            percentage:'',
            net: '',
            igst: '',
            cgst: '',
            sgst: '',
            total_invoice: ''

        });
    }

    show1(){
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';
    }
    show2(){
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display='block';
    }




    render() {

        return (
            <div classname="masterfile-add" >
                <form className="masterfileadd-form">
                 <p>
                    <input type="radio" value="igst" onClick="show1()"/>igst
                    <input type="radio" value="sgst" onClick="show2()"/>sgst/cgst
                 </p>

                    <p>
                       <label className="masterfileadd-text">
                        Invoice Date :
                          <DatePicker dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy" selected={this.state.date} onChange={this.handleDateChange} className="itextbox1" />
                       </label>
                    </p>


                    <label className="masterfileadd-text">
                        Company Name:
                              < select value={this.state.company} onchange={this.onChange} name="company_name" className="itextbox2">
                            {this.props.company.map(company => {
                                return <option value={company.company_name}>{company.company_name}</option>
                            })}
                        </select>
                    </label>

                    <p><label className="masterfileadd-text">
                        GSTIN :
                        <input type="text" name="GSTIN" value={this.state.GSTIN} onChange={this.onChange} className="itextbox3"></input>
                    </label>
                    </p>
                    <p><label className="masterfileadd-text">
                        Invoice No :
                        <input type="text" name="invoice_no" value={this.state.invoice_no} onChange={this.onChange} className="itextbox4"></input>
                    </label>
                    </p>
                    **<div id="div1">
                    <p> <label className="masterfileadd-text">
                        Percentage:
                        <NumberFormat name="percentage" value={this.state.percentage} onChange={this.handlenum1Change} className="itextbox5"/>
                    </label>
                    </p>
                    <p><label className="masterfileadd-text">
                        NET :
                        <NumberFormat name="net" value={this.state.net} onChange={this.handlenum2Change}  className="itextbox6"/>
                    </label>
                    </p>
                    </div>
                    **<div id="div1">
                    <p> <label className="masterfileadd-text">
                        Percentage:
                        <NumberFormat name="percentage" value={this.state.percentage} onChange={this.handlenum3Change} className="itextbox5"/>
                    </label>
                    </p>
                    <p><label className="masterfileadd-text">
                        NET :
                        <NumberFormat name="net" value={this.state.net} onChange={this.handlenum4Change}  className="itextbox6"/>
                    </label>
                    </p>**
                    </div>**
                    <p><label className="masterfileadd-select">
                        IGST :
                      <input type="text" value={this.state.igst} className="itextbox7" readOnly />
                    </label>
                    </p>
                    <p><label className="masterfileadd-select">
                        CGST :
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.cgst}className="itextbox8"readOnly />
                    </label>
                    </p>
                    <p><label className="masterfileadd-select">
                        SGST:
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.sgst} className="itextbox9"readOnly />
                    </label>
                    </p>
                    <p><label className="masterfileadd-select">
                        Total Invoice :
                              <input type="text" name="total_invoice" value={this.state.total_invoice} onChange={this.onChange} className="itextbox10"></input>
                    </label>
                    </p>

                    <p className="iButton" ><input type="submit" value="Submit" onChange={this.onChange} onClick={this.onCreate} className="mButtonAdd" />
                    </p>
                </form>

            </div>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    company: state.companyReducer.company,
    error: state.journalReducer.error
});



export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { getCompany }
)(InvoiceSales)
```

I have tried implementing handle change function when a radio button click is performed however I am not successfull in it please do help me find a solution for this thanks in advance

the percentage and net should be able to calculate igst or sgst/cgst based on the radio button click as it can be seen above the implementation I have tried to do does work partially it does only provide me with one default option and does not switch when pressed on the radio button

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or an editable code pen

Comment: https://codepen.io/yashb196/pen/VwvRgPw

Comment: @yashb If I am able to understand your question, basis the choice of user whether IGST or CGST/SGST. You would like the calculation to take place correct?

Comment: @yashb were you able to check if the below-mentioned solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basis my understanding of the question, User would select the type of tax to be calculated, it can be either IGST or CGST/SGST.

If it is IGST, you need the calculation to be done under that scheme and vice-versa for CGST/SGST.

So you need to start by adding a helper/toggler basis the input from radio buttons. 
Once you have that piece of logic in your local state, you can use that local state value to show/hide options or fields for calculation.

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-field-fdt12?file=/src/App.js) to the code sandbox repo.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class Invoice extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      taxType: "IGST",
      invoiceAmount: "",
      taxValue: "",
      inclusiveOfTaxes: null
    };
  }

  // helper to get tax type basis user radio button selection
  getTaxType = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };


  // helper to get value from each field and fill local state
  onChange = e => {
    //to be on a safer side,
    //convert the incoming data In  Number format
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: Number(e.target.value)
    });
  };


  // helper to render IGST fields
  renderIGSTFields = () => {
    return (
      <div className="igst-fields">
        <div className="tax-percentage">
          Tax Percentage:
          <input
            name="taxValue"
            value={this.state.taxValue}
            onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
            type="Number"
            max="100"
            min="1"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="tax-percentage">
          Invoice Amount:
          <input
            name="invoiceAmount"
            value={this.state.invoiceAmount}
            onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
            type="Number"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="tax-percentage">
          Total After Tax:
          {this.state.inclusiveOfTaxes}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };


  // helper to render CGST/SGST fields
  renderCGSGFields = () => {
    return (
      <div className="cgsg-fields">
        <div className="tax-percentage">
          Tax Percentage
          <input
            name="taxValue"
            value={this.state.taxValue}
            onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
            type="Number"
            max="100"
            min="1"
          />
          <div className="tax-breakdown">
            <div id="cgst">CGST: {this.state.inclusiveOfTaxes / 2}</div>
            <div id="sgst">SGST: {this.state.inclusiveOfTaxes / 2}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="invoice-amount">
              Invoice Amount:
          <input
            name="invoiceAmount"
            value={this.state.invoiceAmount}
            onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
            type="Number"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="total-after-tax">
          Total After Tax:
          {this.state.inclusiveOfTaxes}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  // helper to calculate final invoice amount with tax
  calculateTax = () => {
    // Get data from local state for calculation
    const { taxType, taxValue, invoiceAmount } = this.state;
    let total;

    //basis the tax type there can be 2 calculations
    if (taxType === "IGST") {
      //calculate for IGST
      total = 'some new value'
    } else {
      //calculate for CGST/SGST
      total = 'some new value'
    }


    //you know the calculations, this will be the final values
    //using which the final invoice tax values will be calculated
    console.log({ taxValue, taxType, invoiceAmount });

    //as soon as calculations are done, set the local state 
    //in inclusiveOfTaxes variable
    this.setState({inclusiveOfTaxes: total})
  };

  render() {
    const { taxType } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        Select Tax Type
        <div className="tax-buttons">
          IGST
          <input
            id="igst"
            value="IGST"
            name="taxType"
            type="radio"
            defaultChecked={taxType === "IGST"}
            onChange={e => this.getTaxType(e)}
          />
          CGST/SGST
          <input
            id="CGSG"
            value="CGSG"
            defaultChecked={taxType === "CGSG"}
            name="taxType"
            type="radio"
            onChange={e => this.getTaxType(e)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="invoice-data">
          {taxType && taxType === "IGST"
            ? this.renderIGSTFields()
            : this.renderCGSGFields()}
        </div>
        <div calculate-tax>
          <button onClick={() => this.calculateTax()}>Calculate Tax</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Invoice;
```

So basically there are 3 major functions in the component, 
2 of them are quite straight forward, **renderIGSTFields** and **renderCGSGFields**. These functions depending on the current value of TaxType in the local state will change the type of fields visible to the user.

The last major function is the function **calculateTax** this function will take selected tax type (IGST or CGST/SGST) into consideration and do the calculations accordingly.

Finally after having done tax calculations, update the same value in ***inclusiveOfTaxes*** local state variable so that subsequent render will start reflecting the updated total amount with tax inapplicable sections.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for, if not feel free to ask follow up question.

Comment: Sir you have got it right but i wanted the function to be done asynchronously as in i dont want any button when adding the values of net and percentage i have achieved that but i was having a difficulty during toggle from igst to sgst/cgst